# ASP.NET MVC Property (Setter) Injection Outside Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

For WebApi and Action controllers I am easily able to resolve dependencies by applying the [Dependency] attribute.  All other layers throughout the application are also fine by using setter injection.  The problem is when using any other class within my presentation tier it is unable to resolve [Dependency].  I know I could use DependencyResolver.Current.GetService or contructor injection but I am curious as to why the attribute only works within my controllers within the Presentation Tier.

Comment: Can you give some examples of "any other class within my presentation tier"? What kind of classes are these?

Comment: For instance I have a Handler class that manages WebSocket connections.  It is just a standard public class within my UI project.  It is unable to resolve any setter dependencies.  Constructor injection does work though.